# How to list all the names and download Urls from Firebase using React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to display the list of all the files and their download URLs from Firebase using React JS. But I can't do so because there are two separate functions for `listing(listAll())` and getting the URLs (`getDownloadUrl()`).

```
storageRef.listAll().then( res => {

        const download = []

        res.items.forEach( down => {
         down.getDownloadURL().then( url => {

       //  res.items.forEach( item => {

          download.push(url); 
         // console.log(url)
        })
        this.setState({ download: download})
      })
})

storageRef.listAll().then( res => {

        const listItem= []

        res.items.forEach( item=> {


       //  res.items.forEach( item => {

          itemList.push(url); 

        })
        this.setState({ itemList: itemList})
      })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add the download URLs of all files to the state. In that case, you're looking for `Promise.all()`, in something like this:

```
storageRef.listAll().then( res => {
    let promises = res.items.forEach( item => item.getDownloadURL() );

    Promise.all(promises).then((downloadURLs) => {
        this.setState({ download: downloadURLs });
    });
})
```

---

If you also want to store a list of items in the state, you can do that in the same callback:

```
storageRef.listAll().then( res => {
    let promises = res.items.forEach( item => item.getDownloadURL() );

    Promise.all(promises).then((downloadURLs) => {
        this.setState({ download: downloadURLs, itemList: res.items });
    });
})
```

Comment: I actually want both the item list and the download URLs to be on the same map. So that I can actually use the item list to show the corresponding download URL in a table. But as there are two loops I can't figure out how to render the table with both the list and the URL. Can you help with the render?

Comment: You don't need two loops, one is enough. My second snippet does precisely that: it adds an array of download URLs and an array of items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `getDownloadURL()` promise to resolve, and then you can store the value of the `item + URL`:

```js
const accum = [];
projectStorage.ref(rootPath).listAll().then(res => {
    if (res.items && res.items.length > 0) {
        res.items.forEach(item => {
            item.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                accum.push({name: item.name, url: url})
            })
        })
    }
});
```